# Visual C++ Application in C++Builder

Tags: delphi, visual-c++, c++builder

I am using a  vc++ project (it is a gui application and only uses win api) can i use them or convert and use them with c++Builder , I have access  c++builder xe and i am very new to vc++ but i know delphi and have a few knowledge of c++builder . (I know both are c++ but i am talking about ide)

can i use them in c++builder

my application is [sfxzip](ftp://ftp.altap.cz/pub/altap/salamand/sfx7zip.zip)

I allready have a delphi form so i can include it with c++builder project

Comment: this application will not use mfc

Comment: Sorry i did not mention delphi stuffs on fist post

Comment: How to use Visual Studio projects with C++ Builder and how to use Delphi forms in C+ Builder are completely different topics. Please post separate questions about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include Delphi code and forms in a C++Builder project.